# Check for certain string in input box

Tags: excel, vba, search, excel-2010

I am trying to implement a search function including a `AND` and an `OR` function in my macro, what is the correct statement to use in this case?

How do I detect certain words in vba?

```
if input string contains "AND" 
{ 
search for both strings
}

else if input string contains "OR"
{
search for either one 
}

else
{
do regular search
}
```

Comment: Can you provide examples of your input strings?

Comment: @brettdj Apple AND pineapple, Apple OR pineapple, it's basically just a word..

Answer (score 0):

Is it what you are looking for ?

```
Function searchCriteria() As String

    Dim str_input As String
    str_input = InputBox("Please enter the string")

    If str_input <> "" Then

        If InStr(1, str_input, "AND", vbTextCompare) Then
            searchCriteria = "search for both strings"
        ElseIf InStr(1, str_input, "OR", vbTextCompare) Then
            searchCriteria = "search for either one"
        Else
            searchCriteria = "do regular search"
        End If

    End If

End Function
```